# timePicker, how to suppress hours within a range?

Tags: jquery, time

I'm using [Time datePicker](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery) which is great!

```
$(function() {
    $("#appointment_atime").timepicker({
        'minTime': '9:00pm',
        'maxTime': '6:00pm',

    });
```

Is there a way to suppress or hide some hours within that range?

I don't want 12am and 1pm appears as options.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this plugin seems to have no callback to signal the generation of the times, you'll need to create a function that runs through the list to remove the unwanted entries when the list is clicked on.

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/t6DXm/)** that removes 12am and 1pm.

```
$('#basicExample').timepicker({
    'minTime': '9:00pm',
    'maxTime': '6:00pm',
    'step': 60
});
$('#basicExample').on('showTimepicker', function () {
  $('.ui-timepicker-list li').filter(function (index) {
      return ($(this).text() == '12:00am' || $(this).text() == '1:00pm');
  }).remove();
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you think this answered your question, please consider upvoting it and/or making it the accepted answer.

Comment: Any idea on how to tho exactly the same (remove a custom hour) but using date time picker?